# How can I run a test on a production app without leaving trace?

Tags: mysql, database, web-applications, development-environment, production

I am making some changes to a web app developped in PHP+MySQL and after testing everything in development I have uploaded it to production. However, I would like to make sure that everything runs, I may have forgotten some changes from development to production (database connection etc.).

If I run some changes that insert new rows in the MySQL database, removing the new registers and updating the AUTO_INCREMENT value (so that the auto id doesn't reveal that a test has been done and removed), is enough to leave no trace of the test?

Perhaps the question should be more general, how can I test that once in production everthing runs perfectly without leaving those "footprints"?

Thank you!

Comment: This is way too broad for any specific answer since we have no idea what sort of footprint you might leave. The only credible answer is to backup **all** your data and restore it afterwards. That will still leave traces on the timestamps of any affected files, so you also a need a utility to store the timestamps for all affected files and restore them afterwards.There may be other traces I haven't though of. How 'invisible' does this need to be?

Comment: It's not a big deal to be "invisible". I simply don't want to "break" the production information. I know that I have to remove new MySQL table rows and change teh AUTO_INCREMENT so that after user #10, for example, I don't find #12 (if #11 is the removed user), but go for #11. Perhaps there are other hints like this, or not and this is enough.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is of course to use a tools to compare them so nothing is forgotten. But if that is not possible or not doable for some reason, this is what I would do:

You have changes in form of queries that update the database in some way I guess.
And you want to make sure that everything works as expected before letting everyone else to test.

Then take a backup of production and restore it in a new database, now you have the same as in production. Then run your update queries (that you want to run in production) and run your code against this new database. This will be exactly as production will be after the changes. If it works you can safely do the same thing in production or letting the users in if the changes has already been made.

If this is not what you want and you for some reason need to run in the actual production server this is nothing we can help you with. Your server might do several things we don't know about.

Inserting new rows (can be removed and fixed with resetting auto_increment to the correct value if you know ALL the rows that has been updated)
Triggers (when you added/modified/removed) data triggers might have changes other data in the database.
Deleting records, can't be undone

You have also the risk of code that could crash from this change (or an unknown bug) that causes a method to exit before it has finished so some rows could have changed but others not.

There is no way to know all this without knowing your system fully.

Another way is of course to make a backup now and test your things and then delete production and restore it using the backup. But this is not something that I would ever try myself or recommend others to do...